# AdMob kGADSimulatorID compile error for testDeviceIdentifiers

Tags: ios, swift, admob

When running an app with an AdMob banner integrated I get the following message:

```
2020-12-02 00:54:21.835790+0000  <Google> To get test ads on this device, set: GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];
```

However if I convert this to Swift 5 as follows:

```
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = [ kGADSimulatorID ]
```

I get a compile error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject' to expected element type 'Array<String>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'String')
```

The definition of `kGADSimulatorID` is

```
GAD_EXTERN const id _Nonnull kGADSimulatorID;
```

so I'm not sure how to convert this to a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can start the app without setting the test devices and have a look at the debugger output. There you'll find a message like:

```
<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"49cd348fa9c01223dd293bcce92f1e08" ];
```

After that replace above sample identifier with your real identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first `import AdSupport` and then get your mobile [device advertising identifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport/asidentifiermanager/1614151-advertisingidentifier) uuid string. Note that the code below will return `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` if you run it on simulator. You need to run it on a real device:

```
ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier.uuidString // "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Don't forget to [Set up the test device ID in Google admobs](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9691433?hl=en)

Once you have the advertisingIdentifier uuid string just add it to your code:

```
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = [ "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" ]
```